# Why is the probability that the second coin gold equal to the probability that the last coin is gold?

Tags: probability

I was trying to think about the problem:
There are n gold coins, and 2 lead coins inside a box, and the coins are being drawn out, and not being replaced. Why is the fact that the probability for which the second coin drawn out is gold is equal to the probability that the last coin drawn out is gold?

Comment: There's a bijection from the set of possible cases when the second coin is gold, and those when the last is gold by permuting the second and last coins. Given that all cases are equally likely, this means their probabilities are the same.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand bijection...

Comment: In your title, is there any significance to the word "ford"? It seems like it must be a typographical error, but I cannot figure out what the intention might have been.

Comment: @Lee Mosher Sorry, it is a typo. I have changed it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I have many typos, I decided to ask one question at each time. Sorry for any inconvenience caused. i will edit the question.

Comment: Ask yourself, which coin is more likely to be gold, the second coin or the last coin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a matter of choosing which of the $n+2$ draw will be lead, ${n+2}\choose{2}$ possibilities.

For second draw to be gold, we choose which of the remaining $n+1$ draws will be lead, ${n+1}\choose{2}$ possibilities. For last draw to be gold, the same.

Both have probability of $\frac{{n+1}\choose{2}}{{n+2}\choose{2}}=\frac{n}{n+2}$

For consecutive lead, it is a matter of choosing which of the $n+1$ draws will be the first lead. Hint: draw # $n+2$ cannot be the first lead coin since we have $2$ lead coins. Possibilities: $n+1$.

Therefore the probability of drawing consecutive leads is $\frac{n+1}{{n+2}\choose{2}}=\frac{2}{n+2}$, so You’re correct.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: So，the probability that the first coin is gold, and the last coin is gold and the lead coins being drawn out are not conseculative would be:$\frac{n}{n+2} \times \frac{n-1}{n+2} \times (1-\frac{2}{n+2})$?

Comment: Not quite, it is $\frac{n}{n+2}\times\frac{n-1}{n+1}\times\left({1-\frac{2}{n}}\right)$.

Comment: I see, cuz we have to take into account the two golds being drawn. It is quite confusing, i thought it could be a conditional probability.